# How to refresh or call set state for a particular container widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, state, setstate

In my project i have different container widgets that are placed one above the another in a stack layout and i have performed set of canvas drawing on each container widget based on my scenario. My question is "how to refresh or call set state for a particular container widget without rendering all the widgets"?.

Thanks in advance,
Ashwin

Answer (score 1):

You will need transform your "Container" in a custom statefull widget and then make his state management by your needs. Take a look at BLoC pattern [here](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381). With this pattern you will be able to update a specific widget in all widget tree without recreate all widgets.